# execute several "npm scripts" in order

Tags: node.js

I would like to command "electron-packer ." (it takes some time) and then "asar pack app app.asar"

Is it possible to do this?

Or should I simply wait for the first one and command the second?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can queue commands like this.

`npm run pack1 && npm run pack2`

Or you can add another line that does the above and just run that alone.

```
"scripts": {
  "pack": "npm run pack1 && npm run pack2"
}
```

Add this inside your `"scripts"` and you can just run `npm run pack` to run both of those commands.